# Bulk Addition of TCP Port in SCOM 2012

Tags: port, scom

I have to add 2,500 TCP Port under monitoring in SCOM 2012. Situation is even worse as there is lot of combinations between watcher node & Target Server. Is there anyway to automate addition of TCP Port using powershell or any other script?

Answer (score 0):

as far as I am aware there is no way of automating this, because there are no PowerShell cmdlets. Other commands cannot be used also, the research shows. So you'll have to to some authoring here. There is a MP:

Custom TCP Port Monitoring Management Pack for SCOM 2012
http://www.systemcentercentral.com/custom-tcp-port-monitoring-management-pack-for-scom-2012/

but I haven't tried it and I cannot give you any feedback. What you can do though is take this approach, which in your case could be more efficient:

SCOM Advanced Authoring : Powershell Discovery from CSV file - Explained using “TCP Port Monitoring” Scenario
http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2015/12/01/scom-advanced-authoring-powershell-discovery-from-csv-file-explained-using-tcp-port-monitoring-scenario.aspx

Hope this helps. Regards,

Stoyan